# How to call a bean method with a parameter which is passed as an attribute

Tags: jstl, javabeans

```
<c:out value="${sessionScope.controller.getQuestion(${requestScope.questionNumber})}"/>
```

where

controller is a bean

getQuestion is a method of a bean

questionNumber is an attribute

when i call bean methods without parameters it works.

```
<c:out value="${requestScope.questionNumber}"/>
```

returns needed value

Answer (score 0):

I think you mean
declaration of the bean and use of the id assigned to the declaration of the bean in the jsp page.

jsp:useBean id="qanda" class=
then
qanda.setQuestion("a question ?");
...
out of time here